# How to Implement Inline Search Without Opening a Modal in Ghost CMS?

Tags: javascript, html, search, content-management-system, ghost-blog

I'm currently working on a Ghost CMS website, and I've followed the documentation provided in the [Ghost documentation](https://ghost.org/docs/themes/helpers/search/) to add a search button. However, by default, the search functionality opens a modal where users can enter their search keywords.

What I'm trying to achieve is to have an inline search feature, where the search input field is visible directly on the page without the need to open a modal.

I would appreciate any guidance or code examples on how to modify the Ghost CMS search functionality to make it inline within the page content. Essentially, I want the search input field to be present and accessible on the page at all times, allowing users to enter their search queries without the need to click a button or open a modal.

Thank you in advance!

I've followed the documentation provided in the [Ghost documentation](https://ghost.org/docs/themes/helpers/search/)